# Change background image with each page visit jquery cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I would like to change background images each time a user visits the site. I'm assuming this could be achieved with the jquery cookie plugin, but I have only found instances where the image can be changed after a set amount of hours, not each time the user visits the page.

Any idea on how to achieve this or tutorials that you all may know of I appreciate it.

Comment: Why do you need to use a jQuery plugin to set or get a cookie? You can do it all with javascript.

Comment: @David- no reason. I had just researched this and jquery cookie kept surfacing in the process so I thought that would be a good place to start.

Comment: If there is a better way, I am def. open to it.

Comment: @DavidChase Why is that important? The OP is using jQuery, and the jQuery cookie plugin makes it easier to work with cookies, so I don't see why they shouldn't use the plugin if they are in need of cookie management

Comment: @Ian I refer you to this [**link**](http://blog.millermedeiros.com/stop-writing-plugins-start-writing-components/) when i can do the same thing a plugin does in three or four basic js functions there is no need for a jQuery plugin...

Comment: @DavidChase I do agree that some things, even this cookie plugin, shouldn't actually be plugins. Cookies have nothing to do with jQuery - management of them could be made into its own mini library. I think people assume that if you're going to use jQuery in your code, it has to be a plugin (or should be). I guess what would've been more helpful is pointing the OP to your 3 to 4 functions or something that's already been created for this. The link you provided is interesting and makes good points, so thanks for that

Comment: @JJM check out the sweet cookie object MDN created for public consumption its called [**docCookies**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie). if you need more help on how to apply it to your situation let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If your talking long term the best way would be server-side. Log their ip address into a database and then check it everytime a person visits the page. If they have been there then load the new image else load first image and lost persons ip address.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array of possible images, you can store the current image index in the cookie. When the page loads, get the current image index from the cookie and increment it modulo the number of images. If it's null, set it to zero instead. Then display the image at this new index and store its value in the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

> I have only found instances where the image can be changed after a set amount of hours

Assume you have five different background-images:
1 => dog, 2 => cat, etc. When the user visits the page you assign him a cookie with the value 1, meaning: This user has seen dogs. When he visits again: Check for cookie. Get the number, increment, show cats and reset cookie with new number (2).